# MySQL query the largest amount present in a collection

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table Teacher that contains a TeacherPIN as well as a table Student that contains a TeacherPIN referencing a Teacher. The idea is that a Teacher contains a certain amount of Students.

I am tasked with finding the teacher with the most students. I am currently using the query:

```
select t.TeacherPIN, count(s.TeacherPIN)
from Teacher t, Student s
where t.TeacherPIN = s.TeacherPIN
  and ((select count(s1.TeacherPIN) from Student s1 where s1.TeacherPIN = t.TeacherPIN) >=
    (select count(s2.TeacherPIN) from Student s2 where s2.TeacherPIN = (select t1.TeacherPIN from Teacher t1)));
```

I'm sure I'm making this way more complicated than I should be, but I've been at it for a while now and am hoping someone could push me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find just one teacher (of possibly many) with maximum number of students:

```
SELECT TeacherPIN
     , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfStudents
FROM Student
GROUP BY TeacherPIN
ORDER BY NumberOfStudents DESC
LIMIT 1
```

To find all of them:

```
SELECT TeacherPIN
     , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfStudents
FROM Student
GROUP BY TeacherPIN
HAVING COUNT(*) =
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfStudents
         FROM Student
         GROUP BY TeacherPIN
         ORDER BY NumberOfStudents DESC
         LIMIT 1
       )
```